# What to check when flute is not hitting higher octave notes?

Tags: flute, repair

When trying to play notes an octave higher on the flute I notice it is really hard for the higher octave to come out and it keeps playing the lower octave instead. I did not notice this problem when I first bought my flute.

Assuming that my technique is correct, which parts of my flute should I be checking to see if anything needs to be repaired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem with your flute.  If there were leaks, you would not be able to play the lower octave.

Getting the higher octave is a matter of technique, which takes time to learn and will sometimes work and sometimes not in the beginning.  The basic idea for producing the higher octave (or any note above the first octave) is to narrow your lips so the flow of air is faster and more focused without necessarily having more pressure.  A good teacher can help you here.

Comment: Okay. I thought the problem was with my flute because I have actually been playing for a few years now, but I haven't practiced regularly lately. I guess I will practice more often and review the relevant technique then.